# Initializing a C++ Structure

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Is there a difference between initializing a structure these two ways:

```
structVar = {}
```

and

```
structVar = {0}
```

Comment: Depends on the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**corrected**

If the structure is an aggregate, the 2 definitions perform the same thing. From the C++11 standard (N3337):

> 8.5.1/7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equal- initializer, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

If the structure contains two members, like

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    double y;
};
```

then `structVar = {}` will value-initialize the members, i.e. they will become zero (or if the members are non-PODs, the default ctor will be called).

The line `structVar = {0}` will initialize only the first member of the struct with zero. Since in this case you have an aggregate, the rest of the members are value-initialized by empty lists, so effectively you have

```
structVar = {0, {} };
```

C++14 added the possibility of aggregate initialization for aggregates containing brace-or-equal initialized members, i.e.

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    double y{1.1}; // or double y = 1.1;
}
```

In this case,

```
structVar = {0};
```

initializes `x` with 0 and `y` with 1.1. This was not possible before C++14.

PS: just tested the code above, clang++ compiles it with `-std=c++1y`, however g++ 4.9.2 rejects it even if I compile with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: `structVar = {0}` will initialize all remaining elements

Comment: @juanchopanza I am trying also to figure this out... From the link I provided it seems that that's true only in C++14, maybe I am misunderstanding something. **the remaining members are initialized by their brace-or-equal initializers, if provided in the class definition**, so if there are no brace-or-equal initializers provided in class, then it seems the rest of the members are default-initialized. Strange, since `char a[10] = {'a'}` **does** value-initialization on the rest of the array elements...

Comment: I added something in my answer. Assuming the struct is an aggregete, `T a = {0};` would be equivalent to `T a = {0, {}, {}, {}};`. The rest depends on what the members of the struct are.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the quote. What changed in C++14 is that aggragates can have brace-or-equal initializers. In C++11 they couldn't, so the aggregate initialization wouldn't apply to such types.

Comment: Ah OK, I see you figured it out by yourself :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza I just checked the C++11 standard (N3337) and indeed you're right. cppreference is confusing, I edited my answer, +1 for yours! Indeed I now realized that in C++14 you can perform aggregate init. with structs that have brace-or-equal initializers.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the nature of the struct.

If it is an aggregate, the two are largely equivalent. However, the first one is general in that it simply value-initializes the struct. The second one requires that the struct's first member be initializable with `0`, and initializes the rest of elements as if they were each initialized by an empty initializer `{}`, in other words,

```
structVar = {0, {}, {}, {}, ..... };
```

so each remaining element is *value-initialized*.

If it is not an aggregate, then it depends on what constructors, if any, have been provided. There simply isn't enough information to say.